# find duplicate values in a column based on user input

Tags: excel, duplicates, inputbox

I'm trying to find the duplicate cells in a column. I changed the code from manually giving the range to user defined. But it gives me error. What should be modified from the below code to take user input and process.

```
Sub DupEntry()
Dim cel As Variant
Dim rng As Range
Dim clr As Long
Dim colname As Variant
Dim j As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

colname = Application.InputBox("Input Column Name")
j = Cells(l, colname).Column
Set rng = Range(j & "1:" & j & Range(j & "1048576").End(xlUp).Row)
rng.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
clr = 3
For Each cel In rng
If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng, cel) > 1 Then
If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range(j & "1:" & j & cel.Row), cel) = 1 Then
cel.Interior.ColorIndex = clr
clr = clr + 1
Else
cel.Interior.ColorIndex = rng.Cells(WorksheetFunction.Match(cel.Value, rng, False), 1).Interior.ColorIndex
End If
End If
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

Here I used inputbox to capture user inputs. But I ended up in few errors. I get *Run time error 1004, Application defined error* Please help me to capture user inputs for select column. Thank You.

Comment: What errors? Please post them. And if possible the line they are happening.

Comment: `colname = Application.InputBox("Input Column Name")
j = Cells(l, colname).Column` i defined like this and pass this `J` in place of  col(i)... I do not know coding, i'm trying to figure out from different examples. I get _Run Time error: '1004' Application error_

Comment: The line you pasted doesnt exist on the code you provided. Are you sure you pasted the right code?

Comment: No. I did not paste the code which i'm working on. It gives me errors. The one i pasted here is the actual code. I need a input box for the same.

Comment: You got it backwards then. You need to post the code that is with errors for us to see what is wrong on it. It is good to see where you took it from, but we need to see the modifications you did. Otherwise its kinda hard to know what went wrong. Please edit the post and add the code that isnt working

Comment: Moacir, please check my updated post. Thank you for the suggestion

Comment: For what I see when you do `j = Cells(l, colname).Column` , it converts the letter you put in your inputbox with the number. 
Try replacing `colname = Application.InputBox("Input Column Name")
j = Cells(l, colname).Column` with `j = Application.InputBox("Input Column Letter")`

Comment: Also replace `Dim j as long` with `Dim j as String`

Comment: Thank You very much sir. Your suggestion helped me. It is working.